# php error in getting multidimensional array through checkbox and textboxes of same row or multiple rows

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, multidimensional-array

i want to fetch multiple textbox values corresponding to the checkbox selected... we can select one or multiple checkboxes at a time and on button click the output i need is like this:
suppose my array is like this:
array1('first','second','third');
array2('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i')
.
and output i need is:-

first,a,b,c 
second,d,e,f 
third,g,h,i

plz suggest me !!
here is my demo code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["button7"]))
{
    if(isset($_POST['check1']))
    { 
    if (is_array($_POST['check1'])) 
        {
                foreach($_POST['check1'] as $key=> $value)
                {
                    echo "<br>checkbox value is $key :". $value;
                        if (is_array($_POST['hindi'])) 
                        {
                              foreach($_POST['hindi'] as $value)
                                {
                                    echo "<br>".$value;
                                }

                        } 
                }
        }
    }
}
?>
<form name="files" action="demp.php"  method="post">
<table width="300" border="1" >
 <tr>
         <th>check value</th>
         <th>English Name</th>
         <th>Hindi Name</th>
  <tr>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{?>
<td><input name="check1[]" class="checkbox2" type="checkbox" id="check1" value="<?php echo "checkboxvalue = ".$i;?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="" name="hindi[]" id="txt1"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="" name="hindi[]" id="txt2"></td></tr>
<?php 
}

?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="button7" value="edit_pdf">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) as

```
$array1 = array('first', 'second', 'third');
$array2 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i');
$first = array_chunk($array1,1);
$second = array_chunk($array2, 3);
foreach($first as $key => $value){
   $result[] = array_merge($value,$second[$key]);
}
print_r($result);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/383195)

Comment: Nice Answer. Got my output. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Uchiha why "recursive" ? in the case `array_merge` fine works?

Comment: @splash58 yep you're right `array_merge` function works fine, while posting an answer I'm thinking about using `array_merge_recursive` differently but posted answer without thinking more about that. Thanks for reminding about that I've updated my answer

Comment: Well, clear :)  I too remembered it. But in case of numerous indexes, it works not  properly :(

Comment: Yep you're right. Can you make that case with fiddle @splash58. Thanks

Comment: @splash plz give your feedle demo,  we will also take your demo if it suit :)

Comment: Seems, my English is very bad :) I only wanted to say, that thought to use this function too as Uchiha, but did not even tried, because it is not suited to this question

Comment: Yep you're right this question is not suited to for that function @splash58